# Obstructions to presenting $\infty$-categories by Reedy categories

Tags: ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory, model-categories, infinity-categories

We know that any locally presentable $( \infty , 1 )$-category admits a presentation by a Cisinski model category. However, I'm not clear on what obstructions there are to chosing a category $A$ to use for a presentation of a given $( \infty , 1 )$-category.

Are there any locally presentable $( \infty , 1 )$-categories $\mathfrak{X}$ for which, given any presentation by a presheaf topos $\widehat{A}$ and $A$-localizer $\mathsf{W}$, it can be shown that $A$ is **not** Reedy or squeletique etc?

If so, what are the obstructions?

Comment: Such a category $A$ is not uniquely determined by $\mathfrak{X}$. It is always possible to find $A$ of the form $\Delta/N(C)$ where $C$ is some small category (in particular $A$ is squelettique (hence Reedy elegant)). But you can always find $A$ with arbitrary pathologies.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a reference you might point me towards which describes how one might identify such a small category $C$ and identify the localizer?

Comment: Every locally presentable $\infty$-category is the ($\infty$-categorical) reflective localization of an $\infty$-category of $\infty$-presheaves on a small $\infty$-category $C$. Every $\infty$-category $C$ can be canonically expressed as an $\infty$-categorical localization of $\Delta/N(C)$ to a set of maps $W_C$ (see for instance 7.3.15 of [Higher categories and homotopical algebra](http://www.mathematik.uni-regensburg.de/cisinski/CatLR.pdf))...

Comment: One can further show that $\text{Psh}_\infty(C)$ is the $\infty$-localization of $\text{Psh}_\infty(\Delta/N(C))$ to the smallest class of maps containing (Yoneda of) $W_C$ and closed under 2-of-3 and pullbacks. Ultimately, the localizer you are looking for will be generated by $W_C$ together with another set of maps determined by how you get the locally presentable $\infty$-category from the presheaves on $C$.